# How to set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto on deployment in Wildfly NOT using persistence.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, wildfly

I need on deployment schema generation for a webapp that uses JPA.
The server is Wildfly 9 with Hibernate as JPA provider.

I can achieve this by adding

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
```

to persistence.xml.

Is there another way to set this property **per webapp** and **on deployment** in Wildfly 9? I also tried hibernate.properties, but this had no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no *webapp specific* deployment property out of the box.

But you can set a webapp specific system property which you reference in your persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit >
  ...
  <properties>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="${mywebapp.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}" />
  </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

A system property can be set in the `standalone.conf`(`.bat`) or in the `standalone.xml`:

```
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:3.0"> 
  <extensions> ... </extensions>
  <system-properties>
    <property name="mywebapp.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
    ...
  </system-properties>
  ...
</server>
```

Only drawback: you will have to set the system property in *every* environment - there is no default value.

Another option is to create an Integrator which sets the value in the settings. Unfortunately the config is read into the *Settings* object at the beginning and *Settings.setAutoCreateSchema()* and the other *hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto* specific properties are package protected, but you can set them with reflection:

```
public class AutoCreateSchemaIntegrator implements Integrator {

  @Override
  public void integrate(Configuration config, SessionFactoryImplementor factory, 
            SessionFactoryServiceRegistry registry) {
    Settings settings = factory.getSettings();

    try {
      Method setter = settings.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setAutoCreateSchema", boolean.class);
      setter.setAccessible(true);
      setter.invoke(settings, myDeploymentSpecificProperty);
    } catch (ReflectiveOperationException | SecurityException e) {
      // handle exception
    }
  }
}
```

You need to write the full qualified class name of that integrator into `META-INF/services/org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator`:

```
com.myproject.AutoCreateSchemaIntegrator
```

This is the best option if you want to determine the hbm2ddl setting dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for this excellent solution. Option 2 does exactly what I want and it works perfectly.

Comment: For the records: Option 2 requires a dependency on `org.hibernate:hibernate-core` with scope=provided.

Comment: For anyone interested: here's a small [demonstration webapp](https://github.com/albers/hibernate-integrator-spike)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Spring and JPA you can define all your persistence info in spring config xml. So you can include hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to it. An example os Spring config file using org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean as EntityManagerFactory:

```
  <!-- DataSource reachable by jndi,  -->
  <jee:jndi-lookup id="myDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/XADatasource" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

  <!-- jpa Properties used later in Hibernate configuration  -->
  <util:properties id="jpaHibernateProperties">
    <prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">
      org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform
    </prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
    <!-- validate | update | create | create-drop --> 
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
    <prop key="javax.persistence.transactionType">JTA</prop>
    <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">AUTO</prop>
  </util:properties>

  <!-- Entity manager definition. No need of persistence.xml -->
  <bean id="myEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
      <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
      </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
      <list>
        <value>com.mycompany.myproject</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPU" />
    <property name="jtaDataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <!-- Hibernate specific params defined previously -->
    <property name="jpaProperties" ref="jpaHibernateProperties" />
  </bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I do not use Spring in my webapp, so I cannot test your solution.

Comment: This solution is not deployment specific and makes no difference to the one with just a `persistence.xml`, as the given configuration file is usually shipped with the same artifact for all deployments. Although it is possible with Spring to use a second deployment specific configuration file, which would be a correct solution for the problem in a Spring application.

Comment: Of course you can read Datasource or hibernate properties from a external properties file using a   <context:property-placeholder location="file:externalFile.properties" />

Answer (score 0):

For wildfly you can use the ${env} expression with a default value:

```
<property name="mywebapp.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="${env.DB_AUTO:validate}"/>
```

Comment: This is an improvement to @Tobias Liefke's property-based solution, but it still has a drawback: It does not run out of the box. You still have to configure wildfly by setting a system property.

The solution with the `Integrator` works better for me because I can have a persistence jar with an unmodified `peristence.xml`. I can then use this original persistence jar in an example webapp that adds the `Integrator`, and this webapp will autoconfigure the server without any previous tweaks.

See the [example](https://github.com/albers/hibernate-integrator-spike).

Comment: Also, this solution is not really **per webapp** because the same persistence jar can be used in multiple webapps.

Comment: The Integrator solution has the drawback that you depend on a specific persistence provider (i.e. hibernate), so that your application is not portable in the sense of just depending on JPA. And of course that you have to write code using reflection ....